# .htaccess not redirecting to 404.php instead shows page name

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Am trying to make a custom 404 page for my website and am having `.htaccess` file in the root directory where am using this rule

`ErrorDocument 404 404.php //I want to redirect to 404`

So when I change a valid file name like `home.php` to `home1.php` it doesn't redirect me instead it echo's `404.php` on that page

Side Note: `404.php` is in the root directory only

Comment: Try giving it a trailing slash, so: ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Comment: @Nikola Tried but no luck

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should do it

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php
```

Comment: Vuhooooooooo I was on local, `directory/404.php` worked for me, +1, will mark your answer as correct soon

Comment: I'm on local too but it was redirecting me to xampp index.php if I type like this ErrorDocument 403 /index.php. My `.htaccess` is in my website folder. Help please..

Answer (score 8):

In your `.htaccess` file, you should be able to use:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

You can set additional error documents using this method, but I'd put them in a separate errors directory:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php
```

Answer (score 4):

you could do the following to 404 old pages with your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

but i would personally recommend

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home.php /home1.php [R=301,L]
```

as this would do a 301 redirect from the old page name to the new page name, so any cached search engine results would still end up at the correct page instead of hitting a 404

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using an Ubuntu distribution, the directive `ErrorDocument` has no effect if it is in the `.htaccess` in `htdocs` directory or elsewhere: it turned out that it should be put in the proper `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/*.conf` file, inside the `<VirtualServer>` directive (for example, if the website is providing https pages, inside the directive `<VirtualHost *:443>`).