# Turning a 404 document into a "routing" script - how do I set the HTTP code?

Tags: php, http

I'm thinking of turning my 404 document into a "routing" script. This is because I'm much more confident with PHP as opposed to mod_rewrite (and I'm pretty certain that the version of Apache used by my host is far from standard) and I could then handle 404 requests with PHP code inside the 404 document.

This works satisfactorily if I redirect to the correct page.

But, If I try to show some content from within the 404 document and, crucially, change the HTTP status code from 404 back to 200 it doesn't work. The status code is always sent as 404. Even if I use the PHP function http_response_code(200) to try and set it.

So, my question is, is there any way to set the response code from within the ErrorDocument ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess not redirecting to 404.php instead shows page name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818694/htaccess-not-redirecting-to-404-php-instead-shows-page-name)

Comment: @Dimitry Not really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a direct answer to this, but this works very well. Here's some mod_rewrite that you can add to the .htaccess in the root dir and it will send all requests to the .router.php script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.+$ .router.php [L]
```

You can then examine the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable to determine what was requested and act appropriately.

Comment: I'll add - after only a day this is proving to be far, far better then mod_rewrite.